# exceptions in python 3

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, syntax

I am trying to make my code raise an exception error if a number that is not related to the menu is entered. Currently my program just terminates.

```
import os
mainfile = open('grades.txt', 'a')
def main():
    choice = 1
    try:
        while choice >= 1 and choice <= 3:
            display_menu()
            choice = int(input('Please enter a number 1- 3 : '))
            if choice == 1:
                student_entry()
            elif choice == 2:
                student_read()
            elif choice == 3:
                quit_choice()
    except ValueError:
        print('an error has occurred\n')
        return main()
    except:
        print(' An error occurred')
        return main()

def display_menu():
    print()
    print('Press 1 to enter student information\n')
    print('Press 2 to read student information\n')
    print('Press 3 to exit program\n')

main()
```

how do i get it to raise an exception when a num outside of the range 1-3 is entered? I have tried a few different things but still haven't figured it out. I could wright an another while statement or add in some elif statments to handle it but i need to actually raise an exception/error.

Comment: `raise ValueError`. [It's all in docs.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)
PS. you should always end `if... elif...` with `else`, to be sure you handle all cases.

Comment: As an aside, those `return` statements are recursive, I don't think that's really what you intended.

Comment: what do you mean by recursive? I was under the impression i needed to state to return to the main function?

Comment: `except:` **Never** use a bare `except`. Specify which exception you want to catch. As it stands your code catches even a `KeyboardInterrupt` which you probably *don't* want to catch.

Comment: @bakuriu noted as well, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [`raise`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) statement, designed to raise one's own exceptions.

Demo:

```
if num not in (1, 2, 3):
    raise ValueError
```

Ideally this would go before you attempt to do anything else with the input.

Comment: Instead of that, the OP could just add an `else` statement since he's already testing for any of those three.

Comment: @SukritKalra That is correct, or better still just add the `if` statement before he does anything else. That would be the best way.

Comment: thanks, I kind of answered my own question after posting, I used an else statement to raise the error.

Comment: @ alex Im waiting for the time limit to kill before I can accept it.... question. You're saying that I should put the "if - raise error" sytanx first? why is that?

Comment: @krona Because there are more possible inputs in existence than just `1, 2, 3`. Putting the `if` statement at the start immediately filters all of those out, saving time.

Comment: Not really. Checking three conditions isn't all that costly and the code looks better and more readable in my opinion.